# Dishwasher still running cold despite heating element and thermostat replacement

Tags: repair, dishwasher

Beko DW603
I’ve replaced both the heating element and the thermostat with new parts. It’s still not heating. Looking online I’ve not been able to find what else could be causing the problem and what else I can do ? Thanks

---

OK. So I took the dishwasher apart again. I tested the old and new heating element with a multimeter and it was ok. Thermostat ok too. So I am thinking it’s the PCB which holds the relay switch. Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: There's got to be a relay somewhere that isn't playing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I’ll look at a schematic diagram I found and see if I can spot any relays. What’s best way to test if they are functioning correctly?
Could it be the PCB?

Comment: This apears to be what I call "throwing parts at a problem" - if you don't isolate an actual cause, it's very easy to spend more replacing parts that were not broken than you'd spend on a whole new unit with a warranty.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to continue troubleshooting the problem.**

If the dishwasher still has power, and assuming that the parts you used for the replacements are actually functional and not defective, and assuming that they were installed correctly, then the issue has been narrowed down to be between the replaced parts and the incoming power.

Comment: Yes. Agree, will look at relay switches between these two

Comment: This is really not an answer and should be removed telling someone to keep troubleshooting without any advice on what to look for is a waste of everyone’s time.

Comment: @EdBeal you are right. Despite how uncomfortable it is to receive, I appreciate your directness, honest and clarity which allows me to be informed and thus learn and improve. As opposed to those that down vote here or behind the scenes leaving confusion and frustration in their path. I will delete my answer soon

Answer (score 0):

the relay that provides power for the heating element is usually on the PCB very often they are “ ice cube “ or smaller in size normally black plastic, or white plastic on consumer electronics. Rarely they are clear but sometimes , when the washer tries to heat the water or dry there should be 120v or 240v depending on your location. Normally you can feel the relay click most are still mechanical, it is possible that it is solid state then there will be no click but the output voltage to the thermostat should be there if not the relay is bad and many times the relay fails if there is a problem with an element or just an old system the contacts get pitted and fail to make complete the circuit.

Comment: Thanks. I will buy a new PCB. 
After that, if it still doesn’t work, difficult to know what to do next !